# What brand set do I have?

Tags: set-identification, clone-brands

I'm trying to find the LEGO-like set I have so I can buy more and I want to make sure they are compatible. The box top says "max" and I have some of the instructions. You can build a castle, a house, ducks, giraffes. I thinks it's 2 different ones honestly. We bought 2. One in a red box and one with bags we added to it.

Comment: Do you have a picture you can include?

Answer (score 6):

I think you have a box of MAX building bricks, a clone brand from ZURU toys.

[image: Box of MAX bricks]